# python regex to count number of lines in a string which has only one specific word

Tags: python, regex

I want to find the number of times a given string is the lone word on a line in my string. For example, if the word was `"max"` and the string was:

```
str = """max
     hello max
     max hi
     max"""
```

The correct  output would be `2`.

I tried using the `re.findall` function:

```
from re import findall
findall(r'^\max\n', str)
```

But it only counted one occurrence of `"max"`:

```
['max\n']
```

Comment: Regexes are context free (chomsky type 2 grammar) so in their purest form they can't count, if I remember well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sum` builtin function:

```
>>> string = \
"""max
hello max
max hi
max"""
>>> sum('max' == line.strip() for line in string.split('\n'))
2
```

The above code works by adding up the number of times the string `max` is equal to the current line in `string`. The sum will be the number of times `max` appears by itself on a line.

Comment: If string = 
' ' ' max max ' ' ' 

above code is giving sum = 1 but it should be only 0 right ?

Comment: @AshishKumar I can't reproduce. I'm getting `0`. Is that string multiple lines?

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 My apologizes, but what exactly is your "yes" referring to? My solution doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

This does the job:

```
import re

str = """max max
     hello max
      max
      max
      max
      max
     max hi
     max"""


res = re.findall(r"(?m)^\s*max\s*$", str)
print res
print len(res)
```

**Output:**

```
['      max', '      max', '      max', '      max', '     max']
5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re

str = """max
  hello max
  max hi
  max"""

results = len(re.findall("^max|max$", str))
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: @Toto no, because the OP wanted the number of times "max" is the lone string in the sentence.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say doesn't work if you have `max` in the middle of the string, add it in a line between `hello max` and `max hi`

Comment: work for """max 
hello max 
max  
max""" ? if you put max in middle it's dosn't work

Comment: @Toto Thank you for pointing that out. I will adjust my solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
string = """max
     hello max
     max hi
     max"""
word='max'
print(sum([1 for elem in string.split('\n') if (word == elem.strip())]))
```

You can also try this